# multiple multi-column selections in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying do multiple multi-column selections from a pandas dataframe and can't seem to find an elegant way to do accomplish it.

Set up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 8)),columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

Let's say I want to find the rows of the dataframe for which columns 'A' and 'B' are greater than 50, I would do something like this:

```
df[['A', 'B']].where(lambda x: x > 50).dropna()
```

Now let's say I also want to select on columns 'E' and 'F' where they are less than 25.

How do I accomplish this?

**Note**: In the actual dataset ['A', 'B'] can be a set of 10+ columns that are non-sequential, and ['E', 'F'] can also be a set of 10+ columns that are non-sequential. I have lists of column names for each set of criteria. So I want to avoid `('A' > 50) & ('B' > 50)` as I would then have to string together 30+ boolean criteria.

Comment: `df[['E', 'F']].where(df[['E', 'F']].lt(25)).dropna()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 8)),columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

Define the columns you want to constrain:

```
columns1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']
columns2 = ['D', 'F']
```

Define and apply constraints

```
constraint1 = (df[columns1] > 50).all(axis =1)
constraint2 = (df[columns2] < 50).any(axis =1)
print df[constraint1 & constraint2]
```

Note:

.any(axis=1) acts as OR operator when applying the constraint to columns.

.all(axis=1) acts as AND operator when applying the constraint to columns.

Comment: Hi @Omar with regards to your note, so what you're saying is that `.all()` means that every column has to meet the criteria, but `.any()` means that at least one column has to?

Comment: Yes .any will return true if anything in the set being examined are true (similar to OR).
.all will return true if all in the set being examined are true (similar to AND).
Specifying axis=1 says check along the columns (axis=0) says check along rows.